# How to create a Heatmap with square axis

Tags: oxyplot

How do you make a heatmap with square axis (equal length axis)?
When I use the following I get a square image but the x-axis span is (-1.8, 1.8) instead of (-1,1)

```
PlotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Heatmap Example" };
PlotModel.PlotType = PlotType.Cartesian;
PlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = -1, Maximum = 1, Title = "U", MajorStep = 0.2 });
PlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Minimum = -1, Maximum = 1, Title = "V", MajorStep = 0.2 });
```

When I set an AbsoluteMinimum and AbsoluteMaximum the image stretches the aspect ratio.

Comment: Have you seen the examples here: http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/series/HeatMapSeries.html? They are using a LinearColorAxis, not a LinearAxis.

Comment: Did you found an answer to your Q?

Comment: I have not found a solution to the problem associated with producing a heatmap with square axis (i.e. equal axis length)

Comment: @user3396724 you may want to look at a solution I found for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513600/how-to-create-square-plot-area-with-oxyplot

Comment: Docs link is now https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/series/HeatMapSeries.html