# How to create square plot area with Oxyplot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm trying to create a square graph (X axis width is the same as the Y axis height).

I can't find any documentation on this and all of the properties I've seen which might be able to do this are inaccessible.

I've tried:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}" Width="500" Height="500"/>
```

This obviously doesn't work because this sets the entire area (not the graph specific portion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by hooking into the `LayoutUpdated` event on the `PlotView` and updating the `PlotView.Width` from the `PlotArea` width/height difference.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding PlotModel}" x:Name="PlotView"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var plotView = (PlotView) this.FindName("PlotView");

            plotView.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;
        }

        private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var plotView = (PlotView) this.FindName("PlotView") ;

            if (plotView.Model != null)
            {
                var widthAdjustment = plotView.Model.PlotArea.Width - plotView.Model.PlotArea.Height;

                plotView.Width = plotView.ActualWidth - widthAdjustment;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want it to be resizable, it works if you wrap it in a `Border` with a `Height` that is equal to the `Width` plus the height of the title section.  For example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Width="200" Height="224">
            <oxy:PlotView x:Name="plot" Model="{Binding Path=PlotModel}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind for the Model object:

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System.Windows;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public PlotModel Model
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        Model = new PlotModel
        {
            Title = "Test",
            TitlePadding = 0,
            TitleFontSize = 24
        };
        LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 0));
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 2));
        Model.Series.Add(line);
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image: the window]

If you want to do a resizable version, then use the containing window's `SizeChanged` event, and re-adjust the size of the `Border` container in that event handler.

Answer (score -1):

How about using an element outside to define the width and height of plotting area, like **Grid** or **Border**

```
<Border width="500" height="500">
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}" />
</Border>
```

Comment: This sets the control to have those dimensions, not the graphing specific (x/y axis length) portion.